# Как зарегистрировать свайп

Tags: javascript

У меня тут вопрос возник. Как с помощью js событий поймать свайп по экрану смартфона?

Comment: Использовать какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку

Comment: 1.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events
2.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove